# There may be no cities with rainy weather

Tags: alloy

Let “Weather” be one of these: `Rainy`, `Sunny`, `Cloudy`.

I can create an Alloy model that says:  “weather” is a relation between City and one Weather.

```
sig Forecast {weather: City -> one Weather}

sig City, Weather {} 

one sig Rainy, Sunny, Cloudy extends Weather {}
```

Here’s a sample instance:

```
Boston – Sunny  
Seattle – Cloudy  
Miami – Sunny
```

Given that model, I should be able to assert: Every City has Weather.

```
assert Every_city_has_weather {
   all forecast: Forecast | all city: City | one forecast.weather[city]
}
```

I can then ask the Alloy Analyzer to check the assert:

```
check Every_city_has_weather
```

The Analyzer returns the expected result: *No counterexample found*

Excellent.

Now I would like to assert that there may be a Weather for which no City has that weather. In the example above, no City has the value Rainy.

I am having difficulty expressing this. I tried this: There is some w: Weather such that there is no City when joining the weather relation with w. Here’s the Alloy assert:

```
assert A_weather_may_not_be_in_any_city {
   all forecast: Forecast | some w: Weather | no forecast.weather.w
}
```

Then I asked the Alloy Analyzer to check my assertion:

```
check A_weather_may_not_be_in_any_city
```

The Analyzer responded with a counterexample (it showed an instance where each Weather value is mapped to a City).

Apparently my logic is not right. Can you think of the right logic for expressing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to see that some instance exists, you should use a run and not a check statement. An assert says something is true of *every* instance.
2. Given that you want to say "There is some w: Weather such that there is no City when joining the weather relation with w", I'd suggest expressing this very directly:

   `some w: Weather | no c: City | ...`